# Stretching a background image to fit iPhone 5 screen

Tags: html, css

I want my background image to look like it does in my mobile emulator. It looks different on my phone. On desktop it works perfectly.

```
body {
    background-image:url('img/bg.jpg'); background-size:cover; background-position:center center; background-attachment:fixed;
    /*background: #2c373b;*/
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

emulated screen (how I want it to look on my iPhone 5S)

[image]

how it looks on my iphone (background super stretched and blurry):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try these additional cross browser styles

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```